# Can I use the same scanner to scan a double and string? Is this "||" an or-statement?

Tags: java, string, if-statement, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
    System.out.println("\nEnter item's price");
    Scanner newItemPriceSC = new Scanner(System.in);
    Double newItemPrice = newItemPriceSC.nextDouble();//stores item price
    String goBack = newItemPriceSC.nextLine();      

    System.out.println("type \"no more\" if there are no more items\ntype any other word to continue");

    String answ = continueEnd.nextLine();               


    if(!(answ.equals("no more"))){
        continue;//if user does not answer "no more!", loop continues
    }

    if(answ.equals("no more") || goBack.equals("no more")){//if user answers "no more!":
```

The last part of the code:

```
goBack.equals("no more")
```

does not trigger the contents of the if-statement (not pictured) and displays the following error-text when I type "no more":

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at Ben_Li_CashRegisterProgram.main(Ben_Li_CashRegisterProgram.java:64)
```

I declare goBack, above as a String, which stores the contents of the next user-inputted String, which will be scanned with newItemPriceSC. I use the same scanner to scan newItemPrice, a double, which executes properly.

Note that the first part of the if-statement does execute the contents of the if-statement:

```
(answ.equals("no more")
```

Comment: What did you find out when you ran this? Have you inspected the variables at runtime to see what they hold?

Comment: @Patrick, when "Enter item's price" is printed, I type "no more." It will then display "Error in main thread" with another few lines of error-text. I haven't checked the variables at runtime

Comment: I believe adding the error text to the question will help the community with helping you understand your issue. It's difficult to guess the error from "it's not working as I want it to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggested improvement although could be re-factored even further;

```
    System.out.println("\nEnter item's price");
    Scanner newItemPriceSC = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please type \"no more\" if there are no more items");
        String answ = newItemPriceSC.nextLine();
        if (!answ.equalsIgnoreCase("no more")) {
            System.out.println(answ.matches("\\d*") ? "Item price: " + answ : "Please enter a numerical value");
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

If you are wondering what the following line does;

```
System.out.println(answ.matches("\\d*") ? "Item price: " + answ : "Please enter a numerical value");
```

This is using something called the ternary operator. It is the equivalent of an if else statement.

```
answ.matches("\\d*") //This is evaluating whether the string matches any digit. This returns true or false.
```

What follows the question mark is what will happen if it evaluates to true;

```
? "Item price: " + answ // This is what will happen if it returns true
```

What follows the colon is what will happen if it returns false, i.e `!answ.matches("\\d*")`;

```
: "Please enter a numerical value" // This is what will happen if it returns false
```

Comment: The reason you are getting the InputMismatchException is probably because you are inputting a non-numerical value when its trying to read a Double by the way. You would also need to amend the regex in the matches to accommodate decimals.